# NodeJS|SailsJS|PassportJS AJAX Authentication: Making Successive Requests for Data

Tags: ajax, authentication, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

## Making Successive Requests for Data

### TL;DR

After authentication, I cannot request data from my app's Front-End -- but only through server-side views and Postman can I make subsequent requests for data after logging in, or by authenticating my user in Postman and then making the data request in my app.

First off, I'm a newbie on the server-side.

I've a SailsJS backend which I'm using for REST. Creating and authenticating a user, using LocalStrategy, works fine -- and really, even making subsequent requests for data works fine -- but not via AJAX from my app.

I can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) or server-side views to access data, such as `/list`; making requests after authentication in my app doesn't work -- **UNLESS** I jump back into Postman and login, then jump back to my app and remake the request.

I do notice that my `set-cookie`'s in my app are different between the first authentication request and the request for `/list`.

If necessary, I can show some code, but this seems I'm missing a very high-level, basic concept in making authenticated AJAX requests.

**EDIT:**
My front-end *is* on a different domain -- Sails runs on `localhost:1337` while my UI runs on `localhost:8100`.

Here's what my `/api/config/cors.js` looks like:

```
module.exports.cors = {

  allRoutes: true,

  origin: '*',

  credentials: true,

  // methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

  // headers: 'content-type'

};
```

I'm using angular on the front-end, and the subsequent requests are using `withCredentials: true` -- do I need to add this to the login request too? Must I send the username/email along in the request also?

How do I allow all my subsequent requests for data authenticated after login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your frontend application has as a different origin than your backend application [the AJAX requests will not include the session cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) by default.

If you are [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

This option has to be used for all AJAX requests, so the server can treat them as belonging to the same session.

You also have to [configure the server side](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/cors-js) to allow CORS requests.

Comment: I made an edit -- please take a look. I am running port `1337` for the server and `8100` on the UI -- I get a `set-cookie` for all requests, but they change from request-to-request.

Comment: Do I need to set withCredentials: true in my 'POST /login' request too? It's already set in my 'GET /list' request.

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the session cookie in all your requests.

Comment: You should use withCredentials everywhere. Every request that doesn't use it will have its own session on the server. You want that all your AJAX requests refer to the same session.

Comment: that worked! I'm extremely grateful for you helping out a novice like myself. I'm gonna accept your answer -- would you mind mentioning you need to send `withCredentials: true` for *all requests* in your answer for future (novice) readers like myself? Thanks very much again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I updated the answer to fit your request.